# Left-adjoint to Yoneda embedding

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, adjoint-functors, yoneda-lemma

Let $C$ be locally small. Consider the Yoneda embedding $Y:C\rightarrow [C^{op},Set]$. Since limits in functor categories are computed pointwise and since the hom-functor preserves limits, the Yoneda embedding is limit-preserving. A natural question to ask then is, whether or when the Yoneda embedding has a left adjoint. Categories whose Yoneda embedding has a left adjoint are called [total](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total+category). Apparently the category of sets and the category of groups are both total.

*What are the left adjoints of the Yoneda embedding (of these or other interesting examples) explicitely?*

Comment: Allegedly locally small cocomplete categories with a dense subcategory are total. $\mathsf{Set}$ has the dense subcategory consisting of a singleton set of your choice. I'm not sure how to join the dots into an explicit adjoint, though

Comment: A natural transformation $F(X)\to \hom_{\mathsf{Set}}(X,S)$ corresponds to a collection of maps $FX\times X\to S$ satisfying naturality conditions. So I think the left adjoint will be a colimit - the disjoint union of the $FX\times X$ modulo some relations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a contravariant functor $F:\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$, we need to find a set $Y$ with a universal natural transformation $F \to \mathrm{Hom}(-,Y)$.

Note that the contravariant functor $\mathrm{Hom}(-,Y)$ (treated as a functor $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$) is left adjoint to itself (treated as a functor $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$).

Let $Y=F(1)$ where $1$ is a singleton set. Then, for any set $X$, there is a natural map $F(X) \to \mathrm{Hom}(X,F(1))$ given by the adjunct of the map $X \cong \mathrm{Hom}(1,X) \to \mathrm{Hom}(F(X),F(1))$ under the above adjunction.

To see that this is universal, let $\eta:F \to \mathrm{Hom}(-,Z)$ be a natural transformation. Then, the induced map $F(1) \to Z$ is just $\eta_1$ (modulo the isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(1,Z) \cong Z$).

This shows that $\mathbf{Set}$ is total.

Comment: To be explicit, the map $F\to\mathrm{Hom}(-,F(1))$ takes $X$ and $y\in F(X)$ to the function $X\to F(1)$ which maps $x\mapsto F(\overline{x})(y)$ where $\overline{x}:1\to X$ is the point function with image $x$

Comment: More conceptually, cocones with vertex $Z$ under a digram $J\colon\mathcal D\to\mathcal C$ weighted by $F\colon\mathcal D^{op}\to\mathcal C$ are natural transformations $F\Rightarrow\mathcal C(J^{op}-,Z)$. The $F$-weighted colimit of $J$ is $Jd$ if $F\cong\mathcal D(-,d)$. But $F\Rightarrow\mathcal Set(J^{op}-,Z)$ are in natural bijection with $J\Rightarrow\mathcal Set(F^{op}-,Z)$. So the $F$-weighted colimit of $J$ is also $Fd$ if $J\cong\mathcal D(d,-)$. Cototality of $\mathcal Set$ follows from $\mathrm{id}_{Set}=J\cong\mathcal Set(\{*\},-)$.